# UICollectionViewCell could not dequeue a view of kind : UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am following Duc Tran's Tutorial on a collection (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB-HKnhOgl8) and when I am running my application,  I keep getting this error:

Thread 1: Exception: "could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier CHALLENGECELL - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

I looked at other solutions for this but none have yielded results.

Here is the code for the view controller that holds the collection

```
import UIKit

class ChallengesViewerViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!




//MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
private var challenges = WeeklyChallenges.createChallenge()
let cellScaling: CGFloat = 1.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let cellWidth = floor(screenSize.width * cellScaling)
    let cellHeight = floor(screenSize.height * cellScaling)
    
    let insetX = (view.bounds.width - cellWidth)/2
    let insetY = (view.bounds.height - cellHeight)/2
    
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: insetY, left: insetX, bottom: insetY, right:    insetX)
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self

}
  

}

 extension ChallengesViewerViewController:     UICollectionViewDataSource{

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return challenges.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CHALLENGECELL", for: indexPath) as! ChallengeCollectionViewCell
   
    
    cell.challenge = self.challenges[indexPath.item]
    
    return cell
}
```

}

Additionally, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0xY0.png) is the storyboard where I am assigning the reusable identifier to the collection view cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `register` the cell that you're dequeuing in `cellForItem` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...
    collectionView.register(ChallengeCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CHALLENGECELL")
}
```

If you're using `Nib` use this instead:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: <#T##String#>, bundle: nil)
collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CHALLENGECELL")
```